# Linking Python to a complex Fortran model which needs to return to the caller

Tags: python, fortran

I have a complex model written in Fortran which is a self contained entity which reads an input file, allocates memory for all the data structures, initializes the model, provides guesses to the solution, uses a derivative-based solver to solve the nonlinear equations, and populates the output structures, deallocates memory, and finishes.

I am able to call this complete model as a once through from Python fairly easily.  This I do as follows:

```
import sys
import ctypes as ct
lib = ct.CDLL('prog.dll')
f = getattr(lib,'M_EXFUN_mp_EXFUN')
f.argtypes = [ct.c_char_p,ct.c_int]
f.restype = None
x = b'x ' + sys.argv[1].encode('UTF-8') + b' debug=yes'
f(x,len(x))
```

However my next task is more complex.  I want to use a Python optimizer which will call my model as an objective function.  That is, the Python optimizer will pass the current values of the independent variables, X, to the Fortran model which will return the value of some defined objective function.

The Python code is pretty simple and looks as follows:

```
def fun(x):
    return f(x)
x0 = [2.0, 0.0]
res = minimize(fun, x0)
```

Where "minimize" is a function provided by the Python library I am using.

The definition of f(x) is deep in my Fortran model, as is the code for estimating the starting values of X.  Clearly I don't want to call my entire model for each function evaluation, not least because it will stop and return, deallocating all data structures, but also because the function evaluation and starting point code are very small parts of the model.

What I need to do is run the Fortran code from Python (which is easy to do), but then that code has to pause and return control back to the Python code where that will start asking for the starting point and repeated function evaluations by coming back into the Fortran code.

Is this possible?  Or am I stretching the Python <> Fortran interface capabilities?

Update#1:  Here is a simplified example for what my Fortran code is doing.  I have a DLL containing a subroutine main2 which allocates memory for the rest of the problem.  It allocates memory for the model variables x(), and the model parameters, par(), and deallocates them on exit. Here is the code:

```
module main2_mod
  contains
    !dec$ attributes dllexport :: main2
    subroutine main2(cc)
    use objfun_mod
    implicit none
    character(*), intent(in) :: cc
    integer :: i, n
    real(8) :: f
    real(8), allocatable :: x(:), par(:)

    n = 5
    allocate(x(n),par(n))
    x(:)   = (/(i,i=1,n)/)
    par(:) = (/(i**0.5,i=1,n)/)

    call objfun(n,x,par,f)

    write(6,'(<n>f6.1,f6.1)') (x(i),i=1,n), f

    deallocate(x)
    deallocate(par)

    return
    end
end module
```

It calls a subroutine objfun in another DLL testobj.dll.  This calculates the objective function, f, given the latest values of x() together with the parameters par() set up in main1.  Here is the code for objfun:

```
module objfun_mod
  contains
    !dec$ attributes dllexport :: objfun
    subroutine objfun(n,x,par,f)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in)  :: n
    real(8), intent(in)  :: x(n)
    real(8), intent(in)  :: par(n)
    real(8), intent(out) :: f
    integer :: i
    real(8) :: ff

    ff = 0.0
    do i = 1, n
      ff = ff + x(i)*par(i)
    enddo
    f = ff

    return
    end
end module
```

Here is the Python code that calls main2:

```
# for ctypes
import ctypes as ct

# load the DLL
lib = ct.CDLL('main2.dll')

# find entry point for function to be called
f = getattr(lib,'MAIN2_MOD_mp_MAIN2')

# specify its argument types
f.argtypes = [ct.c_char_p,ct.c_int]

# specify return type
f.restype = None

# set up the argument to be sent to the function
x = b'x '

# run the function with commandline (x) as an argument
f(x,len(x))
```

This runs fine and prints out X() and f.

The problem I am trying to solve now is using an optimizer to call main2 first (to allocate memory and set up the parameters) and then repeatedly call objfun with different values of x() to get the resultant value of f.

The Python code for this has to look something like:

```
def fun(x):
    return f(x)
x0 = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
res = minimize(fun, x0)
```

The definition of f(x) above must somehow refer to objfun in the Fortran.  Secondly this code must also somehow call main2 to allocate the memory and set up the parameters that objfun requires.  It must not be allowed to complete as this would deallocate the memory for x() and par() that objfun needs.

I suspect I need a callback from the Fortran back to Python, but this is where my knowledge is lacking.

Comment: Do you use one of this [wrapper](https://www.matecdev.com/posts/fortran-in-python.html)? Or how do you wait for the result of the fortrun script. Do you use a threat?

Comment: Many things are possible, with some design changes and restructuring, but we have no idea how your Fortran code actually looks like. This cannot be answered.

Comment: @Hermann12 I have added above my method of calling the Fortran function in the DLL.

Comment: That won't really help much. The main problem will be what the Fortran code allows and how it could be modified.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I will have to create a cut down problem then.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава cut down problem added.  Let me know if that all makes sense!  If not I can add any explanations.